# Laravel Eloquent with the max in second table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I've got two tables: `listings`, which holds the details of a product, and `bids`, which holds the bid history of the site.

For brief relevance, imagine that `listings` has the following fields: **name**, **category_id**, **tagline**, **short_description**, and **seller_notes**.

In `bids` we have two relevant fields: **listing_id**, and **bid_amount**.

For reasons relevant elsewhere, *this needs to be in Eloquent as I need access to the model.*

The issue seems to be with the `MAX` bid amount line or the evaluation of the `bid_amount`—no matter how I approach it, I always end up with an irrelevant result, but there's no apparent error that I can see.

```
$listings = \App\Listing::join('bids', 'listings.id', '=', 'bids.listing_id')->select('listings.*','MAX(bids.bid_amount)');

if( !empty($request->keyword) ) {
    $listings = $listings->where('listings.name','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')
                ->orWhere('listings.tagline','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')
                ->orWhere('listings.short_description','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')
                ->orWhere('listings.seller_notes','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%');
}

if( !empty($request->category) ) {
    $listings = $listings->where('listings.category_id','=',$request->category);
}

if( !empty($request->minimum_bid) && !empty($request->maximum_bid) ) {
    $listings = $listings->whereBetween('bid_amount', [$request->minimum_bid, $request->maximum_bid]);
} else {
    if( !empty($request->minimum_bid) ) {
        $listings = $listings->where('bid_amount', '>', $request->minimum_bid);
    }

    if( !empty($request->maximum_bid) ) {
        $listings = $listings->where('bid_amount', '<', $request->maximum_bid);
    }
}
```

The search is to find results with a current highest bid between `minimum_bid` and `maximum_bid` (fields from the search box). The problem presenting is that there may be multiple listings (`listing_id`) that have a current highest bid (`MAX(bid_amount)`) between those amounts. I want to display the listings where the `MAX(bid_amount)` for that `bid.listing_id` is between `minimum_bid` and `maximum_bid`. This could potentially result in multiple listings.

The equivalent MySQL query should be:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   listings 
       JOIN (SELECT listing_id, 
                    Max(bid_amount) AS bid_amount 
             FROM   bids 
             GROUP  BY listing_id) bids 
         ON bids.listing_id = listings.id 
WHERE  ( listings.NAME LIKE '%keyword%' 
          OR listings.tagline LIKE '%keyword%' 
          OR listings.short_description LIKE' %keyword%' 
          OR listings.seller_notes LIKE '%keyword%' ) 
       AND ( bids.bid_amount > minimum_bid ) 
       AND ( bids.bid_amount < maximum_bid )
```

I know this is something stupid that I'm doing wrong, I just could really use a fresh set of eyes. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Does listing has bid_id? I am confused by your table structure. You are joining listing table by bids.id. `listing.id = bids.id` ?

Comment: Now joining makes sense. Coming on to next question. What do you want exactly? Joining based on a maximum bid amount per listing or you want a single record with a maximum bid amount and listing details?

Comment: You want to display MAX(bid_amount) listing from minimum_bid and maximum_bid filter, is that correct?

Comment: I want to display the `listings` where the `MAX(bid_amount)` for that `bid.listing_id` is between `minimum_bid` and `maximum_bid`. This could potentially result in multiple listings.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out

Comment: I believe the straight MySQL equivalent would be `SELECT * FROM listings JOIN (SELECT listing_id, MAX(bid_amount) AS bid_amount FROM bids GROUP BY listing_id) bids on bids.listing_id=listings.id WHERE (listings.name LIKE '%keyword%' OR listings.tagline LIKE '%keyword%' OR listings.short_description LIKE' %keyword%' OR listings.seller_notes LIKE '%keyword%) AND (bids.bid_amount > minimum_bid) AND (bids.bid_amount < maximum_bid)'`, but the way that eloquent changes MAX() to Aggregate even using raw() throws an error.

Comment: A hint is you need to use Subquery. I tried but no luck. Sorry about that.

Comment: Would a whereHas solve your problem? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the code in the question is that it creates a query that tries to find the maximum bid amount over *all* of the bids when we actually need the max for each group of bids per listing. Let's take a look at how to do this with Eloquent. We'll use [local query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#local-scopes) to encapsulate the logic and clean up the API so that we can call it like this:

```php
$listings = Listing::withMaximumBidAmount()
    ->forOptionalCategory($request->category)
    ->forOptionalBidRange($request->minimum_bid, $request->maximum_bid)
    ->forOptionalKeyword($request->keyword)
    ->paginate($pageSize);
```

I'm assuming that the `Listing` model contains a `bids()` relationship to the `Bid` model:

```php
class Listing extends Model
{
    ...
    public function bids()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Bid::class);
    }
```

Next, let's add the most important scope that maps the maximum bid amount to the model:

```php
public function scopeWithMaximumBidAmount($query)
{
    $bids = $this->bids();
    $bidsTable = $bids->getRelated()->getTable();
    $listingKey = $bids->getForeignKeyName();

    $bidsQuery = \App\Bid::select($listingKey)
        ->selectRaw('MAX(bid_amount) as bid_amount')
        ->groupBy($listingKey);

    $subquery = DB::raw("({$bidsQuery->toSql()}) " . $bidsTable);

    return $query->select($this->getTable() . '.*', 'bid_amount')
        ->join($subquery, function ($join) use ($bids) {
            $join->on(
                $bids->getQualifiedForeignKeyName(),
                '=',
                $bids->getQualifiedParentKeyName()
            );
        });
}
```

This implementation uses metadata on the models and relations to set the table names and columns for the query so we don't need to update this method if those change. As we can see, we first build a subquery to join on that calculates the highest bid for each listing. Unfortunately, much of this isn't documented—the Laravel source code is a necessary reference for advanced cases.

The example above shows how we can provide a raw SQL subquery for the joined table and pass a closure instead of column names to add any specialized clauses for the join. We create the subquery using the standard Eloquent query builder—so we can safely bind parameters if needed—and convert it to the SQL string using the `toSql()` method. This scope adds a `bid_amount` attribute to each `Listing` returned by the call which contains the highest bid.

Here are the remaining query scopes. These are pretty self-explanatory:

```php
public function scopeForOptionalKeyword($query, $keyword)
{
    if (empty($keyword)) {
        return $query;
    }

    return $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->orWhere('tagline', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->orWhere('short_description', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->orWhere('seller_notes', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
    });
}

public function scopeForOptionalCategory($query, $category)
{
    if (empty($category)) {
        return $query;
    }

    return $query->where('category_id', $category);
}

public function scopeForOptionalBidRange($query, $minimum, $maximum)
{
    if (! empty($minimum)) {
        $query->where('bid_amount', '>=', $minimum);
    }

    if (! empty($maximum)) {
        $query->where('bid_amount', '<=', $maximum);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

When we have a desired SQL query to match, the `toSql()` method really helps when constructing a complex query builder object. We may also want to check the indexes on our tables if we experience performance issues. It may be worth indexing `bids.bid_amount` or tuning keyword lookup columns if we have the resources.

Comment: That's just bloody elegant... Thank you. Trying to figure out scopes from the documentation just made me feel like I put my head in a blender. Thank you so much because the setup I had was going to sink our server by month 6.

Comment: @stslavik You're welcome! By the way, I updated the last scope. `BETWEEN` isn't needed--it's equivalent when both less than and greater than are present. Also `BETWEEN` is *inclusive*, so I changed the operators to behave similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Use **DB::raw** in your **join** query to get the **Max** **bid_amount** as **bid_amount**. I have made some changes in your query and it should work now.

```
$listings = Listing::join(DB::raw('(select listing_id, Max(bid_amount) as bid_amount from bids GROUP BY listing_id) bids'),'bids.listing_id','listings.id');

    if( !empty($request->keyword) ) {
        $listings = $listings->where('listings.name','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('listings.tagline','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('listings.short_description','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')
            ->orWhere('listings.seller_notes','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%');
    }

    if( !empty($request->category) ) {

        $listings = $listings->where('listings.category_id','=',$request->category);

    }

    if( !empty($request->minimum_bid) && !empty($request->maximum_bid) ) {

        $listings = $listings->whereBetween('bid_amount', [$request->minimum_bid, $request->maximum_bid]);

    } else {

        if( !empty($request->minimum_bid) ) {

            $listings = $listings->where('bid_amount', '>', $request->minimum_bid);

        }

        if( !empty($request->maximum_bid) ) {

            $listings = $listings->where('bid_amount', '<', $request->maximum_bid);
        }

    }

    return $listings->get();
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't terribly far off, and this feels pretty hacky... If anyone can advise how to improve, it'd be really helpful. This could easily result in far too many queries, and it's definitely not a best practice by any means. I've just been staring at the damn thing so long that I can't see a better/cleaner way to do it.

```
    // Create an instance that we can refine.
    $listings = \App\Listing::select('*');

    // Check if the keyword search exists in any relevant column.
    if( !empty($request->keyword) ) {
      $listings = $listings->where('listings.name','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')
                  ->orWhere('listings.tagline','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')
                  ->orWhere('listings.short_description','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')
                  ->orWhere('listings.seller_notes','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%');
    }

    // Check if the result is in the requested category.
    if( !empty($request->category) ) {
      $listings = $listings->where('listings.category_id','=',$request->category);
    }

    $listings = $listings->get();

    // Check for a greatest bid between the min and max.
    if( !empty($request->minimum_bid) || !empty($request->maximum_bid) ) {
      if( !empty($request->minimum_bid) ) {
        $listings = $listings->filter(function($listing) use( $request ){
          return \App\Bid::getCurrentHighestBid($listing->id) >= $request->minimum_bid;
        });
      }

      if( !empty($request->maximum_bid) ) {
        $listings = $listings->filter(function($listing) use( $request ){
          return \App\Bid::getCurrentHighestBid($listing->id) <= $request->maximum_bid;
        });
      }
    }

    // We're left with a collection, but we need to paginate the results.
    // We use the collection to perform a secondary query to get only the
    // relevant rows. *cough*hack*cough*
    $listings = \App\Listing::select('*')->whereIn('id', $listings->pluck('id'))->paginate(30);

    // Pass it on to the view.
    return view('listings.main', ['listings' => $listings]);
```

I really hope this can help someone, and that it could be improved upon. Laravel has user friendly documentation, but seems to lack a real in-depth reference, so I'm never quite sure if the functions are being used quite the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct, you want to grab all the listings between minimum_bid and maximum_bid, and sort them by listing_id?

You can do this:

```
//This gets you array of collections sorted by listing_id and sorted from 
  highest bid_amount to lowest.
 $listings = Listing::join('bids', 'listings.id', '=', 'bids.listing_id');

if (!empty($request->minimum_bid)  && !empty($request->maximum_bid)) {

    $listings->whereBetween('bid_amount', [$request->minimum_bid,   
        $request->maximum_bid]);

} else {

    if( !empty($minimum_bid) ) {

        $listings->where('bid_amount', '>', $request->minimum_bid);

    }

    if( !empty($request->maximum_bid) ) {

       $listings=$listings->where('bid_amount', '<', $request->maximum_bid);
    }

}

$listings = $listings->get()
    ->sortByDesc('bid_amount')
    ->groupBy('listing_id');
```

Result looks like this(i tested with two listings):

```
    Collection {#196 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    2 => Collection {#184 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => Listing {#204 ▶}
        1 => Listing {#208 ▶}
        2 => Listing {#207 ▶}
      ]
    }
    1 => Collection {#197 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => Listing {#203 ▶}
        1 => Listing {#205 ▶}
        2 => Listing {#206 ▶}
        3 => Listing {#202 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This was one of the first ways I approached it, but unfortunately since there are many bids for each listing, the return set was all the bids for the listings. Then taking the max to get the highest only returned the one result with the highest bid.  Thank you though!